# Random selection with conditional probabilities

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have list say `y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 23, 12, 24, 43, 10]` and I want to make a random selection from it with conditional probability. A number greater than 10 in the list has a probability of say 0.8 of being selected while the rest have probability 0.2 of being selected.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you provide code, or at least an interface? It's hard to even begin without knowing, for example, if the list can contain duplicates, if the cutoff is always 10, if it's > 10 or >= 10, if the list is static or it's a parameter that changes, etc. :)

Comment: I tried this and it gave errors: import numpy as np

y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 23, 12, 24, 43, 10]
for i in y:
    if i > 8:
        print(np.random.choice(len(y), size=1, replace=True, p=0.9))

    else:
        print(np.random.choice(len(y), size=1, replace=True, p=0.1))

Comment: What do you mean by a "random selection"? What will the final output look like? Please provide an example along with a description in words how that example is generated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since random.choice provides a uniform distribution, you will have to work in two steps.  First select between the groups of values (below 10 and above 10).  Then select a value within the group.

To get different probabilities between groups, you can create a list with the appropriate number of repetitions of each group.  For example, for 0.2 and 0.8 you would have 2 instance of the "below10" group and 8 instances of the "above10" group in the list.  This will transform the regular distribution into a weighted distribution relative to each group.

```
import random

treshold = 10
y       = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 23, 12, 24, 43, 10]
group1  = [v for v in y if v <  treshold]
group2  = [v for v in y if v >= treshold]

def getValue():
    group = random.choice([group1]*2 + [group2]*8)
    return random.choice(group)
```

To test if the distribution is as required, you can use the function a large number of times and calculate how many times a value in each group was selected.

```
lowCount  = 0
highCount = 0
N         = 10000
for _ in range(N):
    v = getValue()
    if v < treshold:
        lowCount += 1
    else:
        highCount += 1
print(round(lowCount/N,2),round(highCount/N,2))

# 0.2 0.8
```

If you only ever have 2 groups, you could use a simple if-else statement for the selection:

```
def getValue():
    return random.choice(group1) if random.random() <= 0.2 else random.choice(group2)
```

**EDIT** For a single value (lets say 23) with a probability of 0.9, the approach is the same:

```
y       = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 23, 12, 24, 43, 10]
group1  = [23]
group2  = [v for v in y if v not in group1]
def getValue():
    return random.choice(group1) if random.random() <= 0.9 else random.choice(group2)

lowCount  = 0
highCount = 0
N         = 10000
for _ in range(N):
    v = getValue()
    if v == 23:        # <== same condition as the grouping rule.
        lowCount += 1
    else:
        highCount += 1
print(round(lowCount/N,2),round(highCount/N,2))

# 0.9 0.1
```

*You have to adjust your testing loop accordingly however*

Comment: Alain, thank you for this input. It is working well. How would it look like if I need JUST 1 of the values in the list y to have the probability say, p =0.9 and the rest to have p = 0.1. Now not working with a group of them.

Comment: It should work. Perhaps your distribution checking loop wasn't adjusted to the new grouping.

Comment: It sure did. This was brilliant approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

try this :
it uses np.random.choice from a list a member of elements with a list that content the propabilité of each  element the for loop will generate that list from the input list:

```
import numpy as np
y = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 23, 12, 24, 43, 10]
t=[]
sup=0
inf=0
for j in y:
    if j>10:
        sup=sup+1
    else:
        inf=inf+1
print(sup)
print(inf)
p=[]
for i in y:
    if i>10:
        p.append(1/sup)
    else:
        p.append(0/inf)
print(p)
x=np.random.choice(y, 100, p=p)

print(x)
```

output

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0]
[12 23 23 43 23 12 12 43 24 12]
```

another output with probability 0.5 and 0.5 :

```
[0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0.05]
[24 24 43  8  4 12 23 24  6  5]
```

another one with :

```
[0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.02]
[24 43 23 24  7 24 12 12 43 24]
```

Comment: Ghassen, thank. I have tried this but the results are not okay. I decided to change the probabilities to 1 and 0 and it was still returning values whose probabilities were 0.

Comment: @EArwa try with the new update you can change the probability for one or 0 two another probability

Comment: Great. Thank you. This seems to work. What if I wanted to ensure that only the greatest element in the list has the highest probability of being chosen, say 0.9, and the rest 0.2? How would the code look like. Sorry, I am not good with syntax, but I understand the flow.

Comment: Meanwhile, I will be testing it with different values and see how it behaves.

Comment: this function will count the member of element grater then 10 in one-side  then divide the probability between all of them equally on the other side it will count the member low then 10 and do the same thing @EArwa you can ask me any time  if there is any confusion

Comment: i will be thankful if you up-vote my answer and check it as a right answer

Comment: I have tested it. It does not return the correct probability distribution. For example,  try implementing a loop that counts the number of times it picks a value greater than 10, and run the loop say counts=100000 times; the ratio of the number of times a value >10 to number of counts should equal 0.8 for sufficient number of counts.

Comment: all numbers greater than 10 or less than will took the same value of probability so you will get what are you looking for i think ,finally i think that you should rate my work now by up-voting it or down-voting if it's not helpful for you

Comment: you are welcome @EArwa; could you please upvote my work